# Is it possible to popup some window above the mainActivity?

Tags: android

I have some listView on my mainActivity - the listView contain names of people. 
I want to make some window popup that will contain all 'more info' about someone that was click on him.

I mean that if the user click on some person form this list - i want to popup some window above the mainActivity and show more information  about that person that was the one who the user click on him

I can't find a way to create the popup window

( AlertDialog is not what i need .. i need dialog that i can edit fully and set data as i want )

Comment: Maybe some form of [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dialog after onClick in listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456660/creating-a-dialog-after-onclick-in-listview)

Comment: :( never used the Dialog before on android dev ... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible

extend Dialog class and make a custom view

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    YourParams yourParams;
    Context context;

    public MyDialog(Context context, YourParams yourParams) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.yourParams = yourParams;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sample);
    // 
    // some code ...
    // 
    }

}
```

then call it like this

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this,yourParams);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow material design guidelines, I think you can make use of [Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html), like here on that middle screen:
[image: ex]
There are many libraries that will help you with this, for example https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet